# Sending message to a friend on facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook, message, friend

I am developing an application which is able to let a user send a message to a friend on facebook. I have looked at Facebook API, Hackbook folder. I used the following code, but it did not work. It seems to ask me to implement a new dialog for it.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("caption", app_name);
params.putString("picture", picture);

dialog(MyClass.this, "send", params, new UpdateStatusListener());
```

Any help is very appreciated !

Comment: Where did the dialog() method that you're using come from?

Answer (score 0):

Check this Snippet for Posting on Friend's wall :

```
try{
    parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
    parameters.putString("target_id", "XXXXX"); // target Id in which you need to Post 
    parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
    String  response = authenticatedFacebook.request(parameters);       
    Log.v("response", response);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```